# How do I install/download the prompt command with NPM for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am relatively new to JavaScript and I can't get NPM to work when trying to install prompt. I am trying to code a program that takes user input from the console and convert it into other variables. What it is supposed to do is ask for the temperature in Fahrenheit take your input and then convert it into Celsius and Kelvin. Does anybody know how to get the prompt command?

Comment: "I can't get NPM to work when trying to install prompt." — What did you try? What was the result? Installing modules is pretty trivial, so with the current state of your question we're likely to just repeat the instructions you've already failed to follow. We need to know what the actual problem is in order to help you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to read a user input, you can use [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline) node modules

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

for more details, see [How do I prompt users for input from a command-line script?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input/)